# Report on number of Automations, Data Extensions, Data Extracts, Data Filters, Emails, etc used in an account

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any easy way to report on the number of Automation, Data Extensions, Data Extracts, Data Filters, Emails, Triggered Sends, User-Initiated sends etc used in a Parent BU and all the child BUs under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

You would be able to grab these numbers through various (and numerous) SOAP API calls and then take those numbers and combine them into a single DE - but this is far from an easy way to gather these and can be resource intensive, both for the build and for the execution.

You could try to talk to your Rep and see if they can either build a custom report inside SFMC (for a fee) to gather this information or if they would be able to provide this to you on a regular interval (likely for a fee).